# Node-SOAP not returning expected result

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I'm trying to connect to a third party web service using node-soap but whenever I use a method from the web service I get a massive object instead of the data which is the correct response.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var soapWSDL = "https://staging.refcheckadvanced.co.za/RefCheck_Integrator/services/v2/RefCheck.svc?wsdl";

soap.createClient(soapWSDL, function (err, client) {
if (err) throw err;
    client.IsHealthy({}, function(err,result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

PHP SOAP Envelope:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:IsHealthy/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Node-SOAP Envelope:

```
    <soap:Body>
        <tns:IsHealthy xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        </tns:IsHealthy>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to configure node-soap to use the same formatting as PHP?

Comment: Have you checked the result object for your desired response?

Answer (score 1):

Is the wsdl generated on the fly or static? it worked briefly for me...

My response was: `{ IsHealthyResult: '2015/02/03 11:56:48 AM' }`

But now when I try node-soap throws an error (which you do not handle)

Try this and you'll (maybe) see that `err` is set:

```
soap.createClient(soapWSDL, function (err, client) {
if (err) throw err;
    client.IsHealthy({}, function(err,result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Returns: `Cannot read property 'Body' of undefined`

Try debugging with [node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector) (cross platform) or [NTVS](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) (Windows + Visual Studio)

You'll see that node-soap catches an exception in `\lib\client.js:183` and sets the error in the callback. Why it briefly worked for me I have no clue... =P

But it's a reminder to always check on `err` in the callbacks

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Please check my edit, I think this may be the problem.